# ¿Como puedo usar mi sidebar activo dentro de otras páginas?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo un problema que es que quisiera que mi sidebar se mantuviera abierto o cerrado así como esté ejemplo de página (https://pixinvent.com/demo/vuexy-vuejs-admin-dashboard-template/demo-1/ui/feather)
Que su sidebar al momento de que abra otra sección de su sub-menu se mantuviera ya sea abierto o cerrado pero el mio lo unico que hace es que si abro el sidebar y me cambio de página con las opciones del sub menú esté inmediatamente se vuelve a cerrar. Y me gustaría que tuviera esa función como el ejemplo que puse de la página web.

```
<div class="sidebar close">
        <div class="shadow">
        <div class="logo-details">
        <div class="home-content">
         <i class='bx bx-menu'></i>
          </div>
          <div class="Logo">
          <img src="img/Logo.png" width="180" align-text="center" alt="profileImg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-links"> 
          <li class="active arrow2">
            <div class="iocn-link">
              <a href="#">
           <span class="link_name">Página de Inicio</span>
              </a>
              <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down arrow'></i>
            </div>
            
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a class="link_name" href="#">Página de Inicio</a></li>
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Resumen de Actividad</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Editar Perfil</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Usuarios</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Suscripciones</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Cambiar contraseñas</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
    
           <li>
            <div class="iocn-link">
              <a href="#"> 
                <span class="link_name" >Página Web</span>
              </a>
              <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down arrow' ></i>
            </div>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a class="link_name" href="#">Página Web</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Selección de Plantilla</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Portada Banners</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Portada - Contenido</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Distribución de Portada</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Páginas estáticas</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Redes Sociales</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Gestión SEO</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Configuración Sitio Web</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
    </ul>
 
     .sidebar {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 260px;
        background: #fff;
        z-index: 100;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }
    
    .sidebar.close {
        width: 78px;
    }
    
    .sidebar .Logo img {
        margin: 45px 0 10px -10px;
        width: 75%;
        height: 75%;
    }
    
    .sidebar .logo-details {
        height: 60px;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    .sidebar .logo-details i {
        font-size: 30px;
        color: #777777;
        height: 50px;
        padding-top: 30px;
        min-width: 78px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 50px;
    }
    .sidebar .logo-details i:hover{
        color:;
    }
    
    .sidebar .logo-details .logo_name {
        font-size: 22px;
        color: #6e6b7b;
      /*--*/
        font-weight: 600;
        transition: 0.3s ease;
        transition-delay: 0.1s;
    }
    
    .sidebar.close  .logo {
        position: static;
        overflow: visible;
    }
    
    .sidebar.close .logo-details .logo_name {
        transition-delay: 0s;
        opacity: 0;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
    
    .sidebar .nav-links {
        height: 100%;
        color: #777777;
        padding: 30px 0 150px 0;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    
    .sidebar.close .nav-links {
        overflow: visible;
    }
    
    .sidebar .nav-links::-webkit-scrollbar {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .sidebar .nav-links ul {
        padding: 10px 15px 0 0;
    }
    .sidebar .nav-links li {
        position: relative;
        list-style: none;
        transition: all 0.4s ease;
        border-radius: 12px;
    }
    /*
    .sidebar .nav-links li{
      background: ; /*Color difuminado pegandole al azul del sombreado del menu #EBF5FF*/
    /*} **/
    .sidebar .nav-links li .iocn-link {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    .sidebar.close .nav-links li .iocn-link {
        display: block;
    }
    
    .sidebar .nav-links li svg {
        height: 30px; /**/
        width: 50px;
        min-width: 50px;
        margin: 2px 15px;
        margin-right:  -4px;
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 50px;
        color: #777777;
     /*Esté cambia todo los colores de tanto iconos como de listado #3399ff */
        transition: all 0.6s ease;
    }
    .sidebar .sub-menu svg{
        margin:0px -100px;
    }
    
    
    .sidebar .nav-links:hover {
        color: #3399ff;
        transition: all 0.6s ease;
    }
    /*LISTA PARA CAMBIAR TAMAÑO DE ICONOS DEL MENU SIDEBAR*/
    .sidebar .nav-links li i{
        height: 43px;
        min-width: 44px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 45px;
        color: #777777;
     /*Esté cambia todo los colores de tanto iconos como de listado #3399ff */
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 700;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: all 0.6s ease;
    }
    
    
    
    
    .sidebar .link_name li:hover {
        color: #3399ff;
        font-family: sans-serif;
      /*Esté cambia todo los colores de tanto iconos como de listado #3399ff*/
    }
    
    .sidebar .nav-links li.showMenu i.arrow {
        transform: rotate(-180deg);
    }
    
    .sidebar.close .nav-links i.arrow {
        display: none;
    }
    
    
    .sidebar .nav-links li a {
        display: flex;
        margin-right: 2px;
        align-items: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        transition: 0.5s;
        font-family: sans-serif;
      /*border:dotted 1px red;*/
    }
    
    .sidebar .nav-links li a:hover {
        color: #000;
    }
    
    .sidebar .nav-links li a .link_name {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: #777777;
     /*Aquí va color gris pero de los titulos de cada Sub-Lista color a usar #3399ff proximamente*/
        transition: all 0.4s ease;
    }
    
    .sidebar.close .nav-links li a .link_name {
        opacity: 0;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
    
    .sidebar .nav-links li a .link_name {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: #777777;
     /*Aquí va color gris pero de los titulos de cada Sub-Lista color a usar #3399ff proximamente*/
        transition: all 0.4s ease;
    }
    
    
    

    .sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu {
            padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
         /*-Primer dato, segundo dato, Tamaño de Menu, Tamaño de lado izquierdo a derecha del SubMenu-*/
            margin-top: -10px;
            background: #fff;
         /*Aquí va el color del rectangulo que sale del menu*/
            display: none;
        }
        
        .sidebar .nav-links li.showMenu .sub-menu {
            display: block;
        }
        
        .sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu a {
            color: #777777;
         /*Color del titulo del sub menu del rectangulito*/
            font-size: 14px;
            margin:2px 4px;
         /*Cambiar tamaño del sub menu*/
            padding: 0 10px;
         /*Tamaño de distancia del sub menu*/
            font-weight: 500;
            white-space: nowrap;
          /*opacity: 0.6;*/
            transition: all 0.3s ease;
        }
        
        
        /**ESTA PARTE ES PARA EL HOVER ACTIVE**/
         .sidebar.close ul .active{
          background: #F2F2F2;
          margin:0 0 0 -3px;
          border-radius: 12px;
         }
        
         .sidebar.close li .active svg{
          color:#3399FF;
         }
         /*
         .sidebar.close ul .active a{
          color:#3399FF;
         }*/
         .sidebar.close li .active a{
          color:#3399FF!important;
         }
         .sidebar.close li .active svg{
          color:#3399FF!important;
         }
         .sidebar ul .active{
          background: #3399FF;
          margin:0 0 0 -5px;
         }
          .sidebar .nav-links .active span{
         color:#FFF!important;
        }
        .sidebar ul .active i{
         color:#FFF;
        }
        
        
        .sidebar li .active a {
         color:#fff!important;
        }
        
        .sidebar .nav-links li .active svg{
         color:#FFF;
        }
        /**
        ul li.active a{
            background: #262626;
            color:#fff;
        }**/
        .sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu a:hover {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        
        .sidebar.close .nav-links li .sub-menu {
            position: absolute;
            left: 100%;
            margin-top: -2px;
            padding: 10px 20px ;
            font-weight: 500;
            
            border-radius: 0 12px 12px 0;
            opacity: 0;
            display: block;
            pointer-events: none;
            transition: 0.5s;
        }
        
        .sidebar.close .nav-links li:hover .sub-menu {
            top: 0;
            opacity: 1;
            pointer-events: auto;
            transition: all 0.4s ease;
        }
        
        .sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu .link_name {
            display: none;
        }
        
        .sidebar.close .nav-links li .sub-menu .link_name {
            font-size: 18px;
            opacity: 1;
            display: block;
        }
        
        .sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu.blank {
            opacity: 1;
            pointer-events: auto;
            padding: 3px 20px 6px 16px;
            opacity: 0;
            pointer-events: none;
        }
        
        .sidebar .nav-links li:hover .sub-menu.blank {
            top: 50%;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
        }
    
<script>
  let sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");
  let sidebarBtn = document.querySelector(".bx-menu");
  console.log(sidebarBtn);
  sidebarBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    sidebar.classList.toggle("close");
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: Bueno, ahora entiendo mejor lo que pides, y la verdad no tengo una respuesta clara, porque entiendo que se puede hacer de diversas formas, a saber las que me imagino: 1) Mediante perfil de usuario, controlando cuando abre y cierra los submenus y manteniendo ese dato en base de datos, y al recargar o cargar una página del mismo dominio y perfil, se recuperen esos datos y el sidebar actue en consecuencia, o bien 2) Mediante un mecanismo similar pero usando pares de valores clave-valor guardados en el navegador del visitante, mediante localStorage o sessionStorage.

Comment: Ese seria el como, pero la implementación seria más costosa de mostrar y mejor que intentes hacerla tu primero y si te surgen dudas actualices la pregunta, o esperes mejores comentarios o respuestas que esta mia.